# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException while try to add views dynamically to linear layout android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I have the following crash when try to add view to linear layout in android.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.q8car.andriod.activity/com.technivance.q8car.view.FilterItemsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

My Code is as following

```
ArrayList<ColorResponse> colors = Q8CarDBManager.getAllColors(FilterItemsActivity.this);
        addColor(-1, null, getString(R.string.no_color));

        if (colors != null && colors.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {

                addColor(colors.get(i).getId(), colors.get(i).getHexaCode(), colors.get(i).getName());
            }
        }

        updateSelectedColor(-1);
```

And the addColor Method as following

```
private void addColor(final int colorId, final String colorHexa, final String title) {

        int padding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.small_margin);

        if (inflatedView == null) {

            inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_color, null);
        }

        if (mLayoutParam == null) {

            mLayoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            mLayoutParam.setMargins(0, 0, padding, 0);
        }

        inflatedView.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParam);

        ImageView colorImage = (ImageView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.color_image);
        TextView colorTitle = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.color_title);

        int color = -2;
        if (PhoneUtils.isEmpty(colorHexa) == false)
            color = Color.parseColor("#" + colorHexa);

        BitmapDrawable drawable = ImageManager.getInstance().getRoundedShapeWithColor(this, R.drawable.no_color, color , true);
        colorImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        colorImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                mColorId = colorId;
                updateSelectedColor(colorId);
            }
        });
        colorTitle.setText(title);

//      if(inflatedView.getParent()!=null)
//          ((ViewGroup)inflatedView.getParent()).removeView(inflatedView);

        inflatedView.setId(colorId);
        mColorsImageViews.put(colorId, colorImage);
        mColorsLayout.addView(inflatedView);
    }
```

Please not that when I create the inflated layout every time it takes a lot of time.

**EDIT**

this is the full stack trace

```
Version Name2.4.13
Version Code
23Android Version5.0.1
Devicesamsung (GT-I9505)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.q8car.andriod.activity/com.technivance.q8car.view.FilterItemsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4212)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4065)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4010)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3986)
at com.technivance.q8car.view.FilterItemsActivity.addColor(FilterItemsActivity.java:297)
at com.technivance.q8car.view.FilterItemsActivity.initializeUIComponentsData(FilterItemsActivity.java:186)
at com.technivance.q8car.view.FilterItemsActivity.onCreate(FilterItemsActivity.java:98)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
... 10 more
```

and the method that create the crash is `addColor [mColorsLayout.addView(mColorInflatedView);];`

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, and indicate what lines in that stack trace correspond to lines in your code listings shown above.

Comment: @CommonsWare please review my edit.

Comment: "and the method that create the crash is addColor [mColorsLayout.addView(mColorInflatedView);];" -- there is no such line in your code. Do you mean `mColorsLayout.addView(inflatedView);`?

Answer (score 1):

The exception message pretty much tells you where the problem is. It seems like your `inflatedView` can only be not `null` when you've already attached it to `mColorsLayout`, and then you try to attach it again. You have to inflate every view separately instead of having a single `View` object declared at the class level for every color.

Comment: It takes a lot of time and slow down the application.

Comment: Then you have to look for other means of optimization. If you want N views on the screen, all of them have to be inflated, there is no workaround.

Comment: The problem that I need to make horizontal list, so I need to add items by myself.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail: "It takes a lot of time and slow down the application" -- then use tools like Traceview to determine where your time is being spent. How big is this `ArrayList<ColorResponse> colors` going to be?

Comment: @CommonsWare it is about  500 color.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail: That is not going to work well. Moreover, I feel fairly confident that you cannot display views for 500 colors at once on most device screens. Use a `RecyclerView` or some variant of `AdapterView`, instead of whatever you are doing now (presumably having all 500 in a `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView` or `HorizontalScrollView`). That way, you will not have to create 500 views, but only a small fraction of that, recycling them as the user scrolls.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can't I add any identifier to the views that make parent view see them different views and accept to add them 

do you have any example of using RecyclerView  to implement horizontal listview in android ?

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail: "Can't I add any identifier to the views that make parent view see them different views" -- no. It is not a question of identifiers. A `View` cannot have more than one parent. "do you have any example of using RecyclerView to implement horizontal listview" -- [yes](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/HorizontalVideoList), though it is mostly a matter of using `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` when setting up the layout manager.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot I have found the following tutorial that helped me a lot : https://github.com/VenomVendor/RecyclerView/tree/RecyclerView

but my problem now that I want to implement something like notifyDataSetChanged(), do you know any thing that may help me in this ??

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail You just call it on the [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) that's backing your view: `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`.